# Extend the selection area of each item in the various option dialogs

Tags: feature-request, status-review, user-interface

As an example, on the "Share feedback" dialog, I have to click on the `<label>` element to select the relevant option, but the labels don't fit the whole size of the option, so I have to make sure I click on the label text to select the option. The red bits indicate "dead zones" where I *want* to click to select the option, but can't:

[image]

It would be much better if the selection was instead on the element **containing** the labels:

[image]

This is relevant for other dialogs too, e.g. the VTC dialog.

For context, the "Actions" in the review queues, which appear on the right-hand side of the screen, behave as I'd expect, so there's a discrepancy here:

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes please! I'd like to add to this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request):

In some of the option dialogs, the tiny space between the main label and the smaller-text description label is not hittable, which has been a small pain point for me for a while now. I do a lot of flagging and sometimes I use my keyboard, but when I use my pointer, it can be annoying at times. I hit that tiny un-hittable crack surprisingly frequently.